# fopen(uploadedimages/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php

I'm following a tutorial to upload a picture from android to server and i'm using php on server side and this is the code:

```
<?php
    error_get_last();
    chmod("./uploadedimages/", 777);
    // Get image string posted from Android App
    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
    // Get file name posted from Android App
    $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
    // Decode Image
    $binary=base64_decode($base);
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
    // Images will be saved under 'www/imgupload/uplodedimages' folder
    $file = fopen('uploadedimages/'.$filename, 'wb');
    // Create File
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);
    echo 'Image upload complete, Please check your php file directory';
?>
```

When i try to run, it shows me the following errors:

> fopen(uploadedimages/): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in...
>
> fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...
>   fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...

I'm very new to php so please help me ( I've found some answers from the internet but it didn't work for me)

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 3):

You need to give full path of the file in `fopen()`

```
$file = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploadedimages/'.$filename, 'wb');
```

Also make sure you have the **right permissions** to create a file in your server.

And since the file is not getting created in the first place, you are getting errors when you are trying to use `fwrite()` and `fclose()`

Comment: Actually, i get the same errors. I created the file uploadedimages. It exists. How can i make sure that I have the right permissions to create a file in my server.

Comment: Which server are you using?Linux or Windows?

Comment: I'm using apache server integrated in wamp in windows 8

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

The `failed to open stream` error occurs when PHP cannot find the path you have specified. And also in think you didn't specify the file extension so use something like `fopen('uploadedimages/'.$filename.'.png', 'w+')`. The extension can be your preferred choice.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507